# Unable to execute a VBScript (.vbs) from registry

Tags: vbscript, registry, contextmenu

**Forenote:**
Not a duplicate of: [Unable to run vbs file from windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854552/unable-to-run-vbs-file-from-windows-registry)

I've just decided to write a VBScript which handles an argument. Before I start writing it, I'm testing out the argument functionality.

Currently, my script is thus:

```
set arg = WScript.Arguments
msgbox arg(0)
```

To call my script from the registry, I use:
`"%windir%\system32\cscript.exe" "E:\VBScripts\Transcode & Analyse.vbs" "%1"`

However, when called from the registry (through a right click context item), I am presented with an error: [image: error]

I'm not quite sure why this error could occur, so any help would be appreciated!

**Additional information:**
When called from Command Prompt, it functions as intended - with the argument displayed in the messagebox, and no text on the titlebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Described error message occurs in case of misusing *RegKey* data type **declared** (`REG_SZ`) versus data type **saved** (`REG_EXPAND_SZ`):

```
==> reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\T-and-A\command

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\T-and-A\command
    (Default)   REG_SZ    "%windir%\system32\cscript.exe" "E:\VBScripts\Transcode & Analyse.vbs" "%1"
```

You need to use either *expanded* path

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\T-and-A\command
    (Default)   REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "E:\VBScripts\Transcode & Analyse.vbs" "%1"
```

or change *RegKey* data type to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` as follows:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\T-and-A\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%windir%\system32\cscript.exe" "E:\VBScripts\Transcode & Analyse.vbs" "%1"
```

Read in `reg add /?` or [reg.exe: Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) how to change value of empty name `(Default)` for the key to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data type.

Please use your current key name instead of  `T-and-A` in above examples.

Comment: My pleasure. Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) if you find that it solved your problem. @SyntheticAscension